How to run LLama 3 locally using CPU wtih any of the tools (ollama, localllm, openwebui)
I have downloaded the .gguf file for Llama 3, and I want to run the model locally. I have tried using lmstudio, ollama with locallm, and openwebui, but I have not had any success with any of them. Does anyone know how to do this?

current problems :
ollama and locallm are great but they
only work if u pull and download llms through their cli and do not
allow local imports.
#lm studio is the thing that could solve my problem but for unknown  reasones it doesn't work.


note i wanna use CPU

